# How Spring Controller handles multiple request urls

Tags: spring-mvc

How spring container handles any request url that ends with *.do or any urls that contains /rest/, and how to configure that in web.xml file.

Comment: I have used both the request mapping for same Dispatcher Servlet, one url for rest is working fine for web mvc part application is not loading application properly..any suggestions.....?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate more? or give any example.